# Does Gods knows our thoughts?

Tags: gods, hanuman, lakshmi, saraswati

Do Gods know everything about us, like our thoughts and our intentions behind them? 
If yes, then are all 33 crores gods omniscient (all knowing)? 
If demigods are not all-knowing, then how is it that Lord Hanuman is worshipped so much, when indeed he doesn't even know us and our problems?

Do Goddess Saraswati and Goddesses Lakshmi known all about us?

Comment: Hanuman is a Brahman. He is not a demigod.

Comment: @hanugm Hanuman is Brahman? Like they say Shiva Vishnu (Rama) are Brahman? Don’t you have a question on this? I too would love to know when an answer comes on that. Or can you say Hanuman is self realised and therefore Brahman as per advaita?

Comment: Hanuman yes he is described as brahman in shanti mantra of tayttriupanishad but its literal meaning Vayu as such can reveal to eyes the presence of god inside the life breath we take that is the meaning  his not supreme God but he is God of all Gods he is jiva kala abhimani if jiva should be present then it can be known from presence of life breath @hanugm

Comment: @Archit I did not get answer now. But the above comment can be useful.  And some names gives such indication https://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-names/gods/god-hanuman/1000-hanuman-names.html

Comment: @PrasannaR sorry I’m little confused I didn’t get 100% what you said.

Comment: @hanugm Like Sarvasmai namah, Nirgunaya Namah? Hmmm sounds interesting. Then why does Hanuman have Sita Rama Bhakti. Could we see it’s the relation like Shiva and Vishnu who keep worshipping each other? Rama worships Shiva directly in Linga form and Shivansh Hanuman worships Vishnu in Rama form. Both are Brahman?

Comment: @Archit In one of the scripture, it is said that Siva told Vishnu that he will help him on earth. And did it in the form of Hanuman.